# Representative color of Software Development

Tags: color-theory, branding

What are the base colors for software development companies? I mean, when creating a website, a logo, flyers, etc... everything related to branding, and things like that, what are the colors that best fit these kind of companies?

Does it really matter the color?

Comment: no, it doesn't really matter *in general*. For your specific project? Probably.

Answer (score 4):

Just take a look at the logos of software development companies: they have all sorts of colors. There is no color for software development.

I am currently rebranding my company and I'm thinking of three main colors:

- green - for software development from scratch, inspired by the green meadow where things can start to grow
- brown - for software maintenance aka. "brownfield development"
- blue - for debugging, inspired by the deep blue sky or deep blue sea, indicating the depth of the analysis

But note that these colors are planned for the second level of the CI/CD (highlight colors) in order to distinguish departments within a company.

If color matters at all, I'd suggest using a color that does not fit the term "software" but fits the industry or sector.

A recognizable logo is much more important - and that must work in black and white anyway, for printed letters and newspapers etc.